# Gravitational field intensity in mass disk

Tags: galaxies, modified-gravity, galaxy-rotation-curve

To calculate the gravitational field intensity or acceleration in a mass disk (like a galaxy), should I do a(r)=G×Mt/r^2 or a(r)=G×M(r)/r^2 with Mt being the total mass of the disk/galaxy and M(r) the cumulative mass of the disk/galaxy?

Comment: Neither is correct. See eq. 2.14.7 [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Variational_Principles_in_Classical_Mechanics_(Cline)/02%3A_Review_of_Newtonian_Mechanics/2.14%3A_Newton%27s_Law_of_Gravitation).

Comment: There is no “shell theorem for disks”. The [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) works only for spherically symmetric distributions.

Comment: @Ghoster I see that eq. 2.14.7 involves an integral over mass density, which results in the cumulative mass M(r) of my question. Isnt it the same equation then?

Comment: No. The masses at radii greater than $r$ will contribute, because there is no shell theorem for disks.